# PHP PDO - what is the proper usage for multiple connecting classes?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am trying to learn PDO, and all resources say that "with PDO, you only need to connect once per script."

How do I ensure that? Do I have to? What's the best practice?

So let's say I have a PHP file and class called DatabaseConnection that includes my credentials and whatnot, and a method to establish a connection:

Do I make sure to connect to mySQL in the beginning of each page/side effects script?

```
//homepage.php
//create header, body, etc, whatever
//$pdoConnection = DatabaseConnection::CREATE_CONNECTION;
//new Avatar($pdoConnection)
```

Or in classes?

```
//avatar.php
//class Avatar { ...
//$this->pdoConnection = DatabaseConnection::CREATE_CONNECTION;
```

In other words, how would the connection flow?

```
database.php -> homepage.php -> avatar.php?
database.php -> avatar.php?
```

Any additional resources on this topic? Many go in depth about PDO, but I can't find extensive usage examples.

Comment: With true OOP you've only one choice, [passing PDO instance around as a constructor variable when instantiating a new class](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#dependency_injection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not everyone likes singleton style class, but that is one solution. Have an application object/class that you include in every page.

The nice part with this, is that it only connects if/when you use the connection, not all pages may require a db connection

```
class App {

   private static $PDO_INSTANCE;

   public static function getPdoInstance() {
      if (!self::$PDO_INSTANCE) {
         self::$PDO_INSTANCE= // TODO build pdo connection
      }

      return self::$PDO_INSTANCE;
   }

}
```

Then to use it

```
$pdo = App::getPdoInstance();
// do db logic here
```

Addition to original answer

I try to keep all my database access in one set of classes, a common name for that would be the "data access layer" or "data repository".

Those classes are the only ones that needs to know about the pdo connection.

for example

```
class calendar_page {

    function index() {
        $dal_calendar = new DalCalendar();
        $events = $dal_calendar->getEvents();
        // render html using data 
    }
}


class DataAccessLayer {

 private $pdo;

 function __construct() {
    $this>pdo = App::getPdoInstance();
 }

class DalCalendar extends DataAccessLayer  {

    function getEvents() {
          $this->pdo-> // query for events
          return $events;
    }

}
```

Another way you an pass the connection around is by using Dependency injection, you would have to google more info on that, it's not something i can give you a quick example of.

Comment: Hehe, beat me by one minute. :)

Comment: Thank you. I sort of understand this part, my biggest concern is when to use it. So, you would say to include this in every page script, but not in other classes? How would class instances access the connection? Should I pass it down as an argument when creating them? What about classes that always definitely need a connection?

Comment: I have added more info to my answer

Comment: Thank you again. So, it is ok to establish several connections per class/page? Let's say, you get one connection in DalCalendar for getting all the events, and you open one connection in Avatar for getting the user's avatar, and you use both of these classes in page.php. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes that is ok, because it is structured as a singleton, every time you call App::getPdoInstance(), it is returning the same 1 connection to you. It only  creates a new connection the first time you call it.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple solution is to use the Singleton pattern. ¹

The idea is that you have a class with one static method, which returns an instance of your database connection. The connection will be instantiated in the first call of the static method and then reused. For example:

```
class MyPDO
{
    private static $inst;

    public static getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$inst)
            self::$inst = new PDO(/* your connection details */);

        return self::$inst;
    }
}
```

When you want to use the Singleton in a context, inlcude the class file (if you don’t use an autoloader) and you can instantly use the PDO instance:

```
require_once "/path/to/MyPDO.php"; // it’s important to use require_once
$pdo = MyPDO::getInstance();
```

¹ Note that Singleton is considered more of an anti-pattern today and Dependency Injection is prefered, if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well. Although it mirrors the other answer somewhat, the dependency injection bit looks like something interesting to look into. Please explain to me one thing. Where do I include the connection. Is it OK do the Database::INSTANCE() inside another class, like, say, Avatar? That would mean there might be several instances of PDO per page (if there's several avatars). Is that ok? Or should it be only declared at the beginning of every page? How would I pass it doen to classes, then? Arguments? Thank you

Comment: No, the PDO connection itself is only managed within `MyPDO`. Other classes can access it, but they should not manipulate it.

Comment: @DwarfVader If you are using Database::INSTANCE() inside a class (like Avatar for ex.) you are making that class dependent on the Database class. The same applies when you are trying to create an instance of a class (like PDO) inside another class (like Avatar) with `new`. Also, by doing these things, saw from outside, the fact that a class needs and uses a connection would be completely hidden. The *dependency injection* solves these problems. No matter what you choose in order to create your db connection: inject it as argument where it's needed.

Comment: Thank you. This actually cleared up what I really wanted to know most. So, I would want to pass the connection down as an argument whenever creating a new class instance (`$av1 = new Avatar(Database::INSTANCE())`). Is this how you would do it? Maybe give it a variable at the beginning of the file (`$conn = Database::INSTANCE(); [...] $av1 = new Avatar($conn)`)?

Comment: No, you don’t need to inject the instance when using the Singleton. (Google “Singleton” to see actual examples). Simply call the static method from literally anywhere to get the PDO instance and work with it. And if you’re talking about DI, you should use a DI framework such as Symfony, because you certainly don’t want to reimplement all the complexity by yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. You've all been very good help, hope someone else can find this useful in the future too.